# Does BeforeScenarioOutline or AfterScenarioOutline exist?

Tags: specflow, gherkin

When i have Scenario outline with more Examples (2 or more) i would like to have set up for whole set of scenarios done only once, before first scenario start, and then i would like to have something where i would clean all my changes after i finish scenario outline for all examples. 
Right now [BeforeScenario] and [AfterScenario], when applied on Scenario Outline, execute for every example. When i use scenario outline, i would very like to be able to run set up once before first example, and to run clean of all changes after last example in my scenario outline.

Is there any attribute existing for such a case? Or is there any work around for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question indicates a misunderstanding about how scenario outlines work  in specflow.

A scenario outline is just a shorthand way of writing many scenarios. Specflow just generates `n` tests for your outline and the runner may decide to run these in parallel, which would make the before/after scenario outline steps make no sense. What you are asking for is ordered test execution, which is not possible.

To me it sounds like really what you have a feature, so put the scenario outline in a feature by itself with the appropriate before/after steps in the feature

Comment: Well, there is not misunderstanding about how scenario outline behaves. I was just wondering if there exist some hook for case described in question. I was not asking for running scenarios in parallel.

Comment: I was just trying to explain how specflow works internally and using the running in parallel as an example of why hooks in the place you want cannot exist. Specflow is a test generation tool really, it doesn't run the tests. How can you generate several tests and have the runner run them and ensure that those in the outline all get run after the before scenario hook? The runner may run the tests in any order...

Comment: The work around is to put the scenario outline in its own feature and create a specific before feature hook for that feature

Comment: I agree about your proposal, that is one way to handle described situation. Sam, can you clarify more about how i can (runner can) decide to run scenarios in parallel or not? I am (we are) using nUnit for running our scenarios implemented in specFlow.

Comment: Different test runners may run tests differently (later versions support running in parallel, XUnit 3, [NUnit 3](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Framework-Parallel-Test-Execution)) but my point was that specflow doesn't get involved in this, it just generates the tests. Often people want to have a way to run tests in a particular order (which is what you want here really ie run before scenario outline -> run all tests in scenario outline -> run after scenario outline hook) but test runners don't support this, as its not a good idea, and hence why you can't have the hooks you want

Answer (score 2):

All available hooks are listed here: http://specflow.org/documentation/Hooks/

A Before/After- ScenarioOutline is not available, because a Scenario Outline is a parameterized Scenario. It's like a theory in XUnit.
So you want also when you are using a ScenarioOutline to revert your changes for every single example.

Comment: If i have 10 examples in Scenario outline, i want to have 1 before scenario step which would execute before first scenario example, and 1 after scenario step which would execute after execution of last example.